# How to Listen and retrieve warnings in Antlr4

Tags: c#, antlr4

In C# antlr4 library, version 4.13.1, there is a class `BaseErrorListener`, which I can override and use `SyntaxError` to listen for errors. But I can't figure out how to catch warnings, ideally with the position and the message that antlr4 produces, just like for errors. For example:

```
line 1:30 extraneous input ' ' expecting {'team:', SKIP_SPACE}
```

This is what I see in console output, but I want to catch it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```cs
var source = "...";
var lexer = new YourLexer(CharStreams.fromString(source));
var tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
var parser = new YourParser(tokenStream);

parser.RemoveErrorListeners();
parser.ErrorHandler = new DescriptiveBailErrorStrategy();
```

where `DescriptiveBailErrorStrategy` could look like this:

```cs
public class DescriptiveBailErrorStrategy : DefaultErrorStrategy
{
  protected override void ReportNoViableAlternative(Parser recognizer, NoViableAltException e)
  {
    var inputStream = (ITokenStream)recognizer.InputStream;
    var message = "no viable alternative at input " + this.EscapeWSAndQuote(inputStream == null
      ? "<unknown input>"
      : e.StartToken.Type == Lexer.Eof ? "<EOF>" : inputStream.GetText(e.StartToken, e.OffendingToken));

    throw new Exception(message);
  }

  protected override void ReportInputMismatch(Parser recognizer, InputMismatchException e)
  {
    var message = "mismatched input " + this.GetTokenErrorDisplay(e.OffendingToken) + " expecting " +
                  e.GetExpectedTokens().ToString(recognizer.Vocabulary);

    throw new Exception(message);
  }

  protected override void ReportMissingToken(Parser recognizer)
  {
    var expecting = GetExpectedTokens(recognizer);
    var message = "missing " + expecting.ToString(recognizer.Vocabulary) + " at " +
                  GetTokenErrorDisplay(recognizer.CurrentToken);

    throw new Exception(message);
  }

  protected override void ReportUnwantedToken(Parser recognizer)
  {
    var message = "extraneous input " + this.GetTokenErrorDisplay(recognizer.CurrentToken) + " expecting " +
                  this.GetExpectedTokens(recognizer).ToString(recognizer.Vocabulary);

    throw new Exception(message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Should I call base methods in each of the ones that I overwrite?

Comment: You should do what makes sense to you, or makes sense in your use case(s).